# How can I delete some questions and import the old answers back from the tokens in Limesurvey?

Tags: limesurvey

The issue is that, I need to delete some questions from an activated survey. For that what I did is:

1.Export answers in .VV
2.Deactivate survey
3.Remove questions that I do not need anymore.
4.Activate survey.
5.Import automatically the tokens from before.
6.Import answers from .VV

In the last step I get no answers, I guess because now the structure of the survey has change. I tried deleting the answers from the .VV that have no question anymore, but doesn´t work.
How can I fix it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your LimeSUrvey version ? You save the file in TSV format (Tab seperated value) ? And maybe some issue depending of the DB : the system with VV2 file was tested with MySQL and PGSQL, not with mssql.

Comment: It is LimeSurvey version 1.87+. No, I have just in CSV format. I will try with TSV and delete the columns, to see if limesurvey get the answers.

Comment: I manage to do it saving it as a .tsv file. The only thing is that I just can now look at the answers into browse responses, and not on token management, that I could before. Thank you very much for your answer Denis.

Comment: With 1.87+, VV export/import are surely buggy. ALl is rewriten now. Happy if it woark.